# What to use to fill a 2" x 12" gap in a dark walnut hardwood floor

Tags: woodworking, hardwood-floor

I need to replace a 12" x 10" supply register grill with a 12" x 8" supply grill (because I need a booster fan grill and the largest size they come in is 12" x 8") leaving me with a 2" gap along the bottom of the register grill.

What's the easiest way to fill that 2" gap in the hardwood floor opening in a way that doesn't stand out?  If I can find a nice reducer frame, that would be nice but I can also take suggestions for other simple suggestions as well.

The smaller size doesn't matter with the supply duct since the duct below is a round oval about 10x4... with the supply duct before the elbow being a larger rectangle.

Here is the original supply grill before I will replace it with a shorter grill.

[image]

Here it is after

[image]

Maybe there is a way to add a frame or something to surround it?

Comment: Picture added with original grill, imagine new grill is 2” shorter leaving a gap

Comment: Matching to the wood floor would hard, suggest using two 1 inch pieces of light colour wood to frame it.  Too bad duct is oval, or a duct booster could have been used.  Maybe get some duct adapters to change oval to round duct.

Comment: @crip659 I might be able to swap out the elbow since it goes from rectangular duct to a round oval elbow for some reason... would the duct booster fit in the elbow?  the duct underneath is actually rectangular so maybe there is a rectangular booster as well?

Comment: Do know that there rectangular to round adapters.  Most duct boosters are just short round duct with a fan in it.

Comment: You are putting a grill with push buttons on the floor?  Aren't the cracks around those buttons going to fill with schmutz?

Comment: Rather than match a filler piece to the colour of the flooring you could match the colour to the grill using spray paint or a custom mix.

Comment: Matching stained wood is as much art (if not more) as it is science. I'd suggest taking a look at the `finishing` tagged items at [woodworking.se] to see what you can learn there.

Comment: Also, that looks a lot more like stained oak than walnut, at least to my eye.

Comment: Now that you've [cross-posted](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/13249/how-to-fill-2-x12-gap-in-hardwood-floor-with-something-that-looks-nice) this to woodworking, want to delete it from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build and stain a little frame that goes around the existing cut out that the fan would sit inside. That flooring looks like oak that's been stained dark brown.

Answer (score 0):

Why make this hard? Trying to patch wood strips into your existing floor will look “patched”.  Find an alternate sized floor register.

If you can’t find the size in your existing design, use a totally different design so it doesn’t look like a mistake. Try this site:

https://ventcoversunlimited.com/cast-iron-scroll-grilles/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwrJOMBhCZARIsAGEd4VFJ6qhzdlgssxstAKxfXe5Gp-qF2GGwemEM6tuNWS31nCEvQMfKUusaAopzEALw_wcB

Or try a custom register:

https://www.pacificregister.com/product/custom-aluminum-laser-cut-vent-covers/?lv=LCA-Various&gclid=Cj0KCQjwrJOMBhCZARIsAGEd4VHTno6tjhMD6Cz692rGhExapdzzYqVhUBCMKCl_MJpMFNtix0mvz6UaAjn5EALw_wcB

You didn’t mention if the size was id or od.

Comment: I needed to put the booster fan in and it doesn't come in the larger size registers